# Alamofire SwIft 3.0 @escaping attribute error

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to manually add Alamofire into an iOS project using these instructions on their website

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

and I have the following iOS error...

[image]

It says @escaping attribute only applies to function types, which I assume is some Swift 3.0 specific thing that has come up. I got four lines with this error?

But no idea how to fix it?

Comment: Think I fixed it, found an article suggesting escaping us the default in swift 3.0 and I can simple delete it. DId so and the error has gone away and the initial test I just did worked!! holding my breath now...

Comment: Your code seems to compile without errors in Xcode 8 GM (*with* @escaping).